# Jackson / JavaTimeModule - handle different timezone offset formats

Tags: java, jersey, jackson, java-time, datetime-parsing

I'm calling an API (using Jersey) which returns Date Time with zone offset. Sometimes the data is in this format:

```
"2017-03-28T14:40:00+01:00"
```

and sometimes it is in this format  (I've no control over this)

```
"2017-03-28T14:40:00+0100"  (where the ':' in timezone offset is missing).
```

I want to marshal these into `java.time.ZonedDateTime` objects. I'm using `JavaTimeModule()` in my Jersey `ObjectMapper`.

```
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

**The Question** : Is there any way to get make the object mapper flexible enough to handle time zone offset in `+01:00` or `+0100`?

Comment: As far as I know, the JavaTimeModule only "understands" ISO formats, which require the "`:`" in the timezone. You will probably need to write a custom (de-)serialiser. That shouldn't be too complicated.

Answer (score 6):

You can specify a pattern with optional sections (delimited by `[]`), to indicate that the offset can have 2 different formats, and add this to the respective field using the `@JsonFormat` annotation.

I've created this test class:

```
public class SampleType {

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss[XXX][XX]")
    private ZonedDateTime date;

    // getter and setter
}
```

Note the last part (`[XXX][XX]`): each pair of `[]` is an optional section, so the parser tries to parse each one, if present. `XXX` is the offset with `:` and `XX` is the offset without it (for more details, take a look at the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendPattern-java.lang.String-))

With this, both formats can be read:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

// offset with ":"
String json = "{ \"date\": \"2017-03-28T14:40:00+01:00\" }";
SampleType value = mapper.readValue(json, SampleType.class);
System.out.println(value.getDate()); // 2017-03-28T13:40Z[UTC]

// offset without ":"
json = "{ \"date\": \"2017-03-28T14:40:00+0100\" }";
value = mapper.readValue(json, SampleType.class);
System.out.println(value.getDate()); // 2017-03-28T13:40Z[UTC]
```

---

Note that the resulting `ZonedDateTime`'s value is converted to UTC: `2017-03-28T13:40Z[UTC]`

If you want to keep the original offset, just use the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature` class to configure the `ObjectMapper`:

```
// add this to preserve the same offset (don't convert to UTC)
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE, false);
```

With this, the offset is preserved (value is not converted to UTC), and the output for the tests above will be `2017-03-28T14:40+01:00`.